# BEM syntax in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, bem

I have a simple HTML and CSS with BEM. I want style for class **.block__item-header-mark** inside class **.block__item-header--has-round**.
I use CSS **.block__item-header--has-round .block__item-header-mark { /*styling here*/ }**. But I don't think this is good syntax.

My question is:

1. How to call .block__item-header-mark inside .block__item-header--has-round with better syntax in my SCSS code ?
2. My BEM syntax is good ?

#### Code

```css
.block {
  &__item {
    &-header {
      &--has-round {
        /* How to call .block__item-header-mark with better syntax ??? */
        .block__item-header-mark {
          /*overide style*/
        }
      }
      &-mark {
        /*normal style*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__item">
    <div class="block__item-header block__item-header--has-round"><span class="block__item-header-mark"></span></div>
    <div class="block__item-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a perfectly fine approach.

Comment: BEM classes on your HTML is perfect. On CSS, I don't think you need to use all the hierarchy as if you need some selector to override your style, the math will be hard. Limit the specificity of your CSS selector as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable to refer to the scope you want

```css
.block {
  &__item {
    &-header {
      $header: &;
      &--has-round {
        #{ header }-mark {
          /* override style */
        }
      }
      &-mark {
        /*normal style*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `&--has-round &-mark` <- wouldn't this violate BEM?

Comment: @zerkms I don't think it violates, but then again, I haven't used BEM in a while and I could be wrong

Comment: https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/ "this block structure is always represented as a flat list of elements in the BEM methodology:" BEM implies you don't use cascade.

Comment: @zerkms `has-round` is a modifier, so the actual mistake I see is it should be `&_has-round &-mark`

Comment: Yep, but `&--has-round &-mark` is cascade and is not "flat" anymore.

Comment: In my head modifiers weren't flat. Cascade has a very different meaning than the opposite of flat, so that got me confused a bit in your second comment.

I'll edit my answer